# Chapter number before Chapter name in LaTeX

Tags: chapters, titlesec

I am trying to get this at the page where my Chapter 1 starts. I am using standard book class. How to get 1. before ChapterName.

[image]

Comment: And completely remove the line with `Chapter 1`? Or should it stay and the number  be printed two times?

Comment: Chapter 1 should also be there.

Comment: Is this repetition logical, or following some occult reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use command `titleformat` in package [titlesec](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf). For more informations chapter 3 of documentation.

```
\titleformat{hcommandi}[hshapei]{hformati}{hlabeli}{hsepi}{hbefore-codei}[hafter-codei]
```

A minimal exemple.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter{. }}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Name}
test
\end{document}
```

[image]

with Chapter 1 should also be there

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\Large}{\chaptertitlename \hspace{2ex}\thechapter}{4ex}{\thechapter \hspace{2ex}}[]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Name}
test
\end{document}
```

[image]

or in Memoir class

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\chapterstyle{crosshead}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Name}   
    test 
\end{document}
```